# JSON- PHP- AJAX - Imposible saber cual es el error al realizar una consulta json

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json

Comunidad, me encuentro desarrollando un panel de gestion de proyectos, al cargar un listado de proyecto el json cae en el .fail, me fue imposible saber cual fue el error luego de intentar varias formas de depurar termine realizando la pregunta en este foro.

Lo siguiente corresponde al controlador:

```
public function listarProyecto(){

    $dao = new ProyectDAO;
    $result = $dao->listarProyecto();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $idProyecto     =   $row['idProyecto'];
        $nombProyecto   =   $row['nombProyecto'];
        $codeProyecto   =   $row['codeProyecto'];
        $tipoProyecto   =   $row['tipoProyecto'];
        $estadoProyecto =   $row['estadoProyecto'];
        $nombUser       =   $row['nombUser'];

        $resultSet[]    = array('idProyecto'    =>  $idProyecto,
                                'nombProyecto'  =>  $nombProyecto,
                                'codeProyecto'  =>  $codeProyecto,
                                'tipoProyecto'  =>  $tipoProyecto,
                                'estadoProyecto'=>  $estadoProyecto,
                                'nombUser'      =>  $nombUser,
                                );

    }
    return $resultSet;
}
```

A continuación podran ver mi funcion que recibe la cadena json.

```
function listarProyecto(){

    $.getJSON('loadTableProyecto.htm')
    .fail(function(){ alert("asd"); })
    .done(function(d){
        $('#tableProyect').find('tbody tr').remove();
        for (var i in d){
            var row = $('<tr><td /><td /><tr>');
            row.find('td').eq(0).text(d[i].idProyecto);
            row.find('td').eq(1).append('<i><img src="webapp/styles/img/modificar.png" onclick="modificarProyecto.htm" id="modificarProyecto" name="modificarProyecto" style="margin-left:15px;" height="20" width="20"></i>');
            row.find('td').eq(2).text(d[i].nombProyecto);
            row.find('td').eq(3).text(d[i].codeProyecto);
            row.find('td').eq(4).text(d[i].nombUser);
            row.find('td').eq(5).text(d[i].estadoProyecto);
            row.find('td').eq(6).text(d[i].tipoProyecto);
            row.appendTo($('#tableProyect').find('tbody'));
        }
    });
}
```

si le realizo un var_dump a mi $resultSet por consola puedo ver lo siguiente 
adjunto preview
[image: Preview encontrado al realizar var_dump a la variable $resultSet que nos retorna el controlado a la vista]
[image: Response encontrado al realizar var_dump a la variable $resultSet]
[image: Error al intentar cargar listado de proyectos]

Comment: Intenta con `return json_encode($resultSet);`

Comment: Si entra en el `fail` es que encuentra un problema en el servidor. Pon el `fail` así a ver qué muestra: `.fail(function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
            alert( "Error: " + errorThrown + " " +  status ); } )`

Comment: Me retorno false

Comment: Antonio, por experiencia, lo que resulta más eficaz cuando retornas un JSON desde el servidor es poner un `header` antes de imprimir el JSON, por ejemplo: `header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8"); echo json_encode($resultSet);` y debes asegurarte de que no hay ninguna otra salida por pantalla de ningún tipo, ni siquiera un espacio en blanco, nada de nada. Con eso debería funcionar.

Comment: Estimado, ayer le di varias vueltas al codigo  tenia varios errores, al final termine llegando al siguiente error "Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 parsererror", ahora me encuentro investigando...

Comment: Al parecer es por que le estoy devolviendo un html y no un json pero cuando itero con lo siguiente:

Comment: while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
   $idProyecto  = $row['idProyecto'];
   $nombProyecto = $row['nombProyecto'$resultSet[] = array('idProyecto' => $idProyecto,                                                                                
 Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, array given in

Answer (score 0):

en fail agrega los siguientes parametros jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown para que puedas obtener a detalle el error

ejemplo:

```
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert('getJSON request failed! ' + textStatus); })
```

tambien puedes agregar

```
.error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("error " + textStatus);
        console.log("incoming Text " + jqXHR.responseText);
    })
```

Comment: Gracias, obtuve como resultado "getJSON request Failed! parse error

Comment: ya solo agrega json_encode($resultSet) en tu backend

Comment: Recibí un false como respuesta

Comment: inicializa $resultSet=array(); como un arreglo

Comment: Gracias, pero no tuve exito, estaba leyendo que podría ser que tenga que aplicar utf8_encode a mi arregleo, si esto es asi tendré que iterarlo mientras aplico el utf8_encode o basta con $resultSet = utf8_encode($resultSet);???

Comment: posible mente es por que en los textos de tus campos contengas acentos y habría que aplicarle utf8_encode